# Should the #X format specifier really make the "0x" prefix upper-case?

Tags: python

I am attempting to use the `#X` format specifier to print a hexadecimal value using capital letters for the "digits" while automatically prepending the usual `0x` prefix. For example, decimal `10` should be represented as `0xA`.

However, that specifier does not seem to behave in that way:

```py
>>> print(f'{10:#X}')
0XA
>>> '{:#X}'.format(10)
'0XA'
```

Which looks like the `X` modifier makes the **whole** string representation of the number (including the `0x` prefix) go through [`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) instead of the "number part" only. I thought that was fair enough but, after checking the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), it looks like it might not be the intended result (or, at least, it is not clearly documented). Here are the relevant bits:

> The `'#'` option causes the "alternate form" to be used for the conversion. [...] For integers, when [...] hexadecimal output is used, this option adds the prefix [...] `'0x'` to the output value.
>
> [...]
>
> The available integer presentation types are:
>
> | Type | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | [...] | [...] |
> | `'x'` | Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using lower-case letters for the digits above 9. |
> | `'X'` | Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, **using upper-case letters for the digits above 9**. |
> | [...] | [...] |

And this seems to imply that  upper-case letters should only be for non-decimal hexadecimal digits (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`) and therefore should not concern `x` (from `0x`); is that right?

Comment: Indeed the documentation seems inaccurate, so you could [submit an issue](https://bugs.python.org/) to update the documentation on that behavior.

Comment: It might be intended behaviour, but they should put it more clear on the docs, look at my answer for a way to do it like you would expect

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, #X makes everything uppercase and #x makes everything lowercase. If you want the 0x to be lower and the rest uppercase then you could try something like this:

```
# will print 0xA
print(f'{10:#X}'.replace('0X', '0x'))
```

In my opionion capitalizing the x in 0x is dumb and they shouldnt have implemented it this way, but it is what it is...

**edit:**
You can remove the # and then it will remove the 0x entirely, you can then add the 0x manually in the format string, this is the best way in my opinion:

```
print(f"0x{10:X}")
```

Comment: I wonder if anyone actually uses `#`.   0XABC looks incorrect IMOH.  I always do it the "best way" above.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yea exactly

Comment: That "best way" doesn't work right for negative numbers, though.